# Reuse spinner in sync methods without repeating code

Tags: node.js

In our code, we repeat the same sequence multiple times: starting a spinner, then execute a `spawnSync` method and update the spinner depending on result. For example here is one of the method:

```
cloneSync() { 
  const spinner = ora({
    text: 'Cloning repository',
    color: 'cyan',
    spinner: 'arrow3'
  }).start();

  let clone = spawnSync('git', ['clone', repository.url, repository.name]);
  if (clone.stderr) {
      spinner.fail('Error while cloning repository');
      throw new Error(clone.stderr);
  } else {
      spinner.succeed('Successfully cloned repository');
      return clone.stdout;
  }
}
```

Another code example so you can see the logic is almost identical:

```
parseLatestTagAndTransmitToDocker() { 
  const spinner = ora({
    text: 'Checking latest tag',
    color: 'cyan',
    spinner: 'arrow3'
  }).start();

  let tag = spawnSync('git', ['describe', '--abbrev=0']);
  if (tag.stderr) {
      spinner.fail('Error while fetching latest tag of repository');
      throw new Error(tag.stderr);
  } else {
      spinner.text(`Successfully retrieved latest tag: ${tag.stdout}`);

      let docker = spawnSync('docker', ['run', 'myimage:latest', tag.stdout]);

      if (docker.stderr) {
          spinner.fail('Error while transmitting tag to docker image');
          throw new Error(docker.stderr)
      } else {
          spinner.success('Successfully transmitted tag to docker service');
          return docker.stdout;
      }
  }
}
```

Is it possible, in node 8+ to wrap this code and make it more reusable. I struggle finding a reusable code without having to trigger spinner and the if/else condition. Doing so with async allow use of try/catch and await/async. But here with sync method, I don't find the proper way to code that kind of behavior.

Comment: Do you have a few more examples?  It's kind of hard to find a pattern in a single code sample.

Comment: Yes I will add it :)

Comment: Ok I added our second example. Pretty similar execpt the method calls two spawnSync in queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the two examples you've provided, I can see a "SpinnerSpawner" function that returns a promise:

```js
function spinnerSpawner(spinnerConfig, cmd, args) {
  if (typeof(spinnerConfig) == "string") spinnerConfig = {
    text: spinnerConfig,
    color: "cyan",
    spinner: "arrow3"
  }
  
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let spinner = ora(spinnerConfig).start,
      tag = spawnSync(cmd, args)
      
    if (!tag.stdError) {
      resolve(spinner, tag)
    } else {
      reject(spinner, tag)
    }
  })
}

cloneSync() { 
  spinnerSpawner("cloning repository", "git", ["clone", repository.url, repository.name])
  .then(function(spinner, proc) {
      spinner.succeed('Successfully cloned repository');
      return proc.stdout;
    }, function(spinner, proc) {
      spinner.fail('Error while cloning repository');
      throw new Error(proc.stderr);
    }
  )
}

parseLatestTagAndTransmitToDocker() { 
  spinnerSpawner("Checking latest tag", "git", ["describe", "--abbrev=0"])
  .then(
    function(spinner, proc) {
      spinner.text(`successfully retrieved latest tag: ${proc.stdout}`)
      return spinnerSpawner("checking docker", "docker", ["run", "myimage:latest", proc.stdout])
    }
  ).then(
    function(spinner, proc) {
      spinner.success("Processing completed")
      return proc.stdout
    },
    function(spinner, proc) {
      spinner.fail(`processing error: ${proc.stderr}`);
      throw new Error(tag.stderr);
    }
  )
}
```

- as always, my code is pseudo-code and not fit for execution - let alone production!

Comment: Doing so make the sync behavior become async in some way, no?

Comment: That depends entirely on the Promise library.  Even so, I'm pretty sure the code would be async-safe.  In `parseLatestTagAndTransmitToDocker()`, I am "chaining" my promises, so the transmit to docker only happens in the  success handler for git.